# Dynamic LAG function (Standard SQL, BigQuery). Is it possible?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag

I am trying hard to find a solution for that. I've attached an image with a overview about what I want too, but I will write here too.

In LAG function, is it possible to have a dynamic number in the syntax?

```
LAG(sessions, 3)
```

Instead of using **3**, I need the number of column `minutosdelift` which is **3** in this example, but it will be different for each situation.

I've tried to use `LAG(sessions, minutosdelift)` but It is not possible. I've tried `LAG(sessions, COUNT(minutosdelift))` and it is not possible either.

The final goal is to calculate the difference between 52 and 6. So, (52/6)-1 which gives me 767%. But to do it I need a dynamic number into LAG function (or another idea to do it).

I've tried using `ROWS PRECEDING AND ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, but again it needs a literal number.

Please, any idea about how to do it? Thanks!

This screenshot might explain it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgg7R.png)

My code: this is the last query I've tried, because I have 7 previous views

```
SELECT 
    DATE, HOUR, MINUTE, SESSIONS, PROGRAMA_2, 
    janela_lift_teste, soma_sessao_programa_2, minutosdelift,
    CASE 
       WHEN minutosdelift != 0 
          THEN LAG(sessions, 3) OVER(ORDER BY DATE, HOUR, MINUTE ASC)
    END AS lagtest,
    CASE 
       WHEN programa_2 = "#N/A" OR programa_2 is null 
          THEN LAST_VALUE(sessions) OVER (PARTITION BY programa_2 ORDER BY DATE, HOUR, MINUTE ASC)
    END AS firstvaluetest,
FROM 
    tbl8
GROUP BY 
    DATE, HOUR, MINUTE, SESSIONS, PROGRAMA_2, 
    janela_lift_teste, minutosdelift, soma_sessao_programa_2
ORDER BY 
    DATE, HOUR, MINUTE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery (as in some other databases), the argument to `lag()` has to be a constant.

One method to get around this uses a self join.  I find it hard to follow your query, but the idea is:

```
with tt as (
      select row_number() over (order by sessions) as seqnum,
             t.*
      from t
     )
select t.*, tprev.*
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.seqnum = t.seqnum - minutosdelift;
```

Comment: Hi, Gordon! Thanks to answer my question here. Sorry for the delay, but as I said to Mikhail I was on vacation and I am working on it now.

Comment: Hi, Gordon! Thanks to answer my question here. Sorry for the delay, but as I said to Mikhail I was on vacation and I am working on it now.

I have tried to use ROW_NUMBER() so far, but I can't really get the right number. I am not sure if I will get to share here, but I will try. I am trying some solutions and I will come back to share with you! Tks

Comment: @julius.86 . . . I don't understand your comment.  This should be implementing the logic that your question asks for.

Comment: Hi, Gordon! Yes, I tried today and worked. Thanks for that!  What I tried to say in last comment it was I tried to use ROW_NUMBER() before my question here and it didn't work. After your comment It worked. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example - hope you can apply this approach to your use case

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 session, timestamp '2021-01-01 00:01:00' ts, 10 minutosdelift  union all
  select 2, '2021-01-01 00:02:00', 1 union all
  select 3, '2021-01-01 00:03:00', 2 union all
  select 4, '2021-01-01 00:04:00', 3 union all
  select 5, '2021-01-01 00:05:00', 4 union all
  select 6, '2021-01-01 00:06:00', 5 union all
  select 7, '2021-01-01 00:07:00', 3 union all
  select 8, '2021-01-01 00:08:00', 1 union all
  select 9, '2021-01-01 00:09:00', 2 union all
  select 10, '2021-01-01 00:10:00', 8 union all
  select 11, '2021-01-01 00:11:00', 6 union all
  select 12, '2021-01-01 00:12:00', 4 union all
  select 13, '2021-01-01 00:13:00', 2 union all
  select 14, '2021-01-01 00:14:00', 1 union all
  select 15, '2021-01-01 00:15:00', 11 union all
  select 16, '2021-01-01 00:16:00', 1 union all
  select 17, '2021-01-01 00:17:00', 8 
)
select a.*, b.session as lagtest
from `project.dataset.table` a 
left join `project.dataset.table` b
on b.ts = timestamp_sub(a.ts, interval a.minutosdelift minute)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hi, Mikhail! Thanks for your answer. I am in my holiday now. As soon as I return I will certainly try that and come back here.

Comment: Hello, Mikhail! Me again here! I am just working on it now and it seems your solution might work well!! Thanks for sharing your knowledge. My only concern is my dataset is not complete by date, hour and minute. So, the script doesn't get minutes before, because there isn't these minutes. But I will make a test with a complete dataset, and I think it will work. I will get back here to let you know! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, Mikhail! Just as you said, it worked to calculate data before. Thanks again for replying me!